# How to extract repeating data separately using re

Tags: python, html, python-re

I have this piece of code with the html contents of a page:

```
page = """<div>
<span class="item_1" dt="2012.03.12">Item Name 1</span>
<span class="item_2" dt="2012.03.6" time="12:51">Item Name 2</span></div>"""

print(re.findall(('class="(a-z_0-9)"')('dt="(0-9.)"')('>(A-Za-z 0-9)<'),page))
```

The last line is not working for me. Maybe it is wrong. What I need to do is to extract class, dt and text for each span separately.

Expected output:

```
[('item_1', '2012.03.12', 'Item Name 1'),
('item_2','2012.03.6','Item Name 2')]
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) needs a **regex pattern** and a string as arguments, so you need to wrap you regex around `r"` and `"` and escape any double quotes in order to have a valid pattern:

```py
re.findall(r"('class=\"(a-z_0-9)\"')('dt=\"(0-9.)\"')('>(A-Za-z 0-9)<')",page)
```

Your regex also doesn't match the info you want. One that does is:

```regex
<span.*class="([^"]*)".*dt="([^"]*)".*>(.*)<\/span>
```

So putting it all together we have:

```py
import re

page = """<div>
<span class="item_1" dt="2012.03.12">Item Name 1</span>
<span class="item_2" dt="2012.03.6" time="12:51">Item Name 2</span></div>"""

print(re.findall(r'<span.*class="([^"]*)".*dt="([^"]*)".*>(.*)<\/span>',page))
```

Which outputs:

```py
[('item_1', '2012.03.12', 'Item Name 1'), ('item_2', '2012.03.6', 'Item Name 2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

*For parsing `html` it's better to use `BeautifulSoup` which makes parsing simple & easy.*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """<div>
<span class="item_1" dt="2012.03.12">Item Name 1</span>
<span class="item_2" dt="2012.03.6" time="12:51">Item Name 2</span></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
div = soup.find('div')

for elem in div.findAll(["span"]):
    print(elem.text, "|", elem.attrs)

Item Name 1 | {'class': ['item_1'], 'dt': '2012.03.12'}
Item Name 2 | {'class': ['item_2'], 'dt': '2012.03.6', 'time': '12:51'}
```